# how to speed up code to get data from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a data frame with id and date as the index and ShopData as the column like so:
[shopdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mByoJ.png)

As you can see, there is a list of dictionaries with 'ValueType' and 'Value' as keys. The idea is to extract the data under 'Value' Key if 'ValueType' equals to 'coffee'. I then need the data to do some calculations.

My code below works but slow:

```
ids = data.index.get_level_values(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(float(0),index = ids , columns=['coffeedata'] )

for i in range(len(ids)):
    for item in data.loc[ids[i], 'ShopData'][0] :
        if item["ValueType"] == 'coffee':
            df.iloc[i]['coffeedata']=  float(item['Value'] )
```

Where is the bottleneck and any idea how to make the code run faster? Thanks!

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: Can you please make the data frame you are using reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data['ShopData'].apply(lambda x: [i['value'] for i in x if i["ValueType"]=='coffee'])
```

It will make a column with lists that contain the values when ValueType is coffee

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
df = data.ShopData.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).apply(
    lambda sd: [ dct['Value'] for dct in sd if dct['ValueType'] == 'coffee'][0] )\
    .astype(float).rename('coffeedata').to_frame()
```

I tested the execution time for a sample of *4000* rows (using *%timeit*).
Your code executed in *5.11 s* and mine in *5.42 ms* (940 times faster).

Comment: much faster than my original solution. Thank you.